# HTML5 drag and drop with only javascript

Tags: javascript, html, events, drag-and-drop

All,

I'm trying to use event delegation, drag and drop and only javascript.

After I double click on item 1 from sourceContainer....the item then gets created in the destinationContainer.  No problem here.

However, when I try to drag the new item in the destinationContainer I can't set the top and left styles for the selected div.  Either the event.target.id or the this.id is always the same.  I expect the id to be 1 which is the newly created id for the div that exists in destinationContainer.

Can anyone help me understand how I might be able to change the top and left style for only the div that was created in destinationContainer.

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mdevera/oys3tLww/1/

Here is the drop function:

```
function drop(event) {

console.log("event.target.id: " + event.target.id);
console.log("this.id: " + this.id);

// This does not allow me to set the selected div's appropriate top and left styles.
// I do not want the whole destinationContainer to not move.  Just the selected child element.

// var offset = event.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain").split(',');
//
// this.style.top = (event.clientY + parseInt(offset[0], 10)) + 'px';
// this.style.left = (event.clientX + parseInt(offset[1], 10)) + 'px';
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/*Drag and Drop events*/
var source;
var before;
function isbefore(a, b) {
    if (a.parentNode == b.parentNode) {
        for (var cur = a; cur; cur = cur.previousSibling) {
            if (cur === b) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function dragenter(e) {
    before =isbefore(source, e.target);
    if (before) {
        e.target.parentNode.insertBefore(source, e.target);
    } else {
        e.target.parentNode.insertBefore(source, e.target.nextSibling);
    }
}
function dragstart(e) {
    source = e.target;
    e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
    e.dataTransfer.setData("Text", source.getAttribute('id'));
    return true;
}
function dragDrop(e) {
    var source = e.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    if (!before) {
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(src));
    }
    ev.stopPropagation();
return false;
}
```

Comment: Hope that helps

Comment: I have not used your example verbatim.  However, I did set the source to be the selected li.  For some reason, the drop event handler sets the selected element to be the parent container (e.g. destinationContainer).  This means you can't use this or event.target to determine which li element was selected.  So instead I set the value of source to be event.target in the drag_start function.  This then allowed me to set the off sets correctly in the drop function.

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>

<div class="dropdown">

    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle"
            type="button" id="dropdownMenu1"
            data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
        Border-style
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
        <li><a href="#" id="border-solid" onClick="return_id(this.id)">Solid</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="border-dashed" onClick="return_id(this.id)">Dashed</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="border-dotted" onClick="return_id(this.id)">dotted</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>


<center><input type="text" id="text1" onClick="ele_id(event)"/></center>
<center><input type="text" id="text2" onClick="ele_id(event)"/></center>

<center><input type="text" id="text5" onClick="ele_id(event)"/></center>
```

Answer (score 0):

Purely in Javascript. Main Point is to play with mouseup,mousedown and mousemove events to simulate drag and drop. Play with offset to get desired offset from mouse cursor of drag object.

**Run code snippet in full page for better view. Scrolling is enemy of drag and drop**

```js
var elements=document.getElementsByClassName("item");
var dest=document.getElementById("dest");


var drag=false;
var tempObj=null; //active  object to drag

//add events to item class 
for(obj of elements)
{
 obj.addEventListener('mousedown',function dragInitiate()
  {
   drag=true;
    tempObj=this;
    
  });
  
  
}
document.addEventListener('mouseup',function dragInitiate(e)
  {
   drag=false;
    if(tempObj!=null)
    {
     if(itemInsideDestination(tempObj,e)==true)
      {
        tempObj.innerHTML="Success!!!";
        dest.appendChild(tempObj);
        tempObj.style.position="relative";
        tempObj.style.left="0px";
        tempObj.style.top="0px";
        
        
        
      }else
        {
          
          tempObj.style.left="0px";
          tempObj.style.top="0px";
        }
      
    }
  });
document.addEventListener('mousemove',function dragStop(e)
  {
   if(drag==true && tempObj!=null)
    {
      //play with offset to get accurate position of item with mouse cursor
      var offset=100;
     tempObj.style.left=(e.clientX)+"px";
      tempObj.style.top=(e.clientY-offset)+"px";
      if(itemInsideDestination(tempObj,e)==true)
      {
        tempObj.innerHTML="I am inside Destination";
      }else
        {
          tempObj.innerHTML="Do not Drop me!!!";
        }
    }
   
  });

function itemInsideDestination(obj,e)
{
 var mx=e.clientX,my=e.clientY;
  var itemRect=obj.getBoundingClientRect();  
  var destRect=dest.getBoundingClientRect();
  
  if((itemRect.left+itemRect.width)>=destRect.left && (itemRect.left+itemRect.width)<=destRect.left+destRect.width)
  {
  if((itemRect.top)>=destRect.top && (itemRect.top)<=destRect.top+destRect.height)
  {
   //console.log('box inside');
    return true;
  }
  }
  
  
}
```

```css
#source
{
 
 border:1px solid gray;
 height:200px;
 width:200px;
}
#dest
{
 
 border:1px solid gray;
 height:200px;
 width:400px;
}
.item
{
  background-color:lightblue;
  width:200px;
  height:30px;
  position:relative;
  border:1px solid gray;
  cursor:move;
}
.inDest
{
  background-color:lightblue;
  width:200px;
  height:30px;
  position:relative;
  border:1px solid gray;
  left:0px;
  top:0px;
}
.item:active
{
  border:1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<p>Source</p>
<div id="source">
  <div class="item">Item1</div>
  <div class="item">Item2</div>
  <div class="item">Item3</div>
  <div class="item">Item4</div>
  
</div>
<p>Destination</p>
<div id="dest">
  
</div>
```